# symfony2 request get gmail alias or string with sign more

Tags: symfony

a gmail alias : `test+alias1@gmail.com`

URL example : `/enabled-account/?mail=test%2Balias1%40gmail.com`

in controller :

```
$mail = $this->getRequest()->get('mail'); // result 'test alias1@gmail.com'
```

missing the sign "more" !

how to recover the initial sign ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache mod\_rewrite %2B and plus (+) signs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523506/apache-mod-rewrite-2b-and-plus-signs)

Comment: You can try adding `getRequestUri()` instead of `get('mail')` after `getRequest()` and filtering the result, but I'm not sure of a better way.

Comment: it's an (bad) alternative and as you this is not the clean way ! thanks