# How can I get value from URL as it is?

Tags: php, get

How can I get the value from URL without replacing + sign with spaces?

URL: https://example.com/platform?id=xxtMEzBG56F3Z2Z+w1VT+g==

Currently, when I try to get variable in PHP by `$_GET['id']` it automatically replaces `+` with `space`. How can I get the real value here?

The value I am getting is `xxtMEzBG56F3Z2Z w1VT g==`, what I want is `xxtMEzBG56F3Z2Z+w1VT+g==`

Comment: Then when you are _creating_ the URL, you should url-encode the `+`.

Comment: Try urlencode($_GET['id']);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523506/apache-mod-rewrite-2b-and-plus-signs might be of help as well

Comment: `urlencode` will convert `=` in `%3D` which I don't want.

Comment: then decode it afterward?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER` with `QUERY_STRING`

```
echo str_replace('id=','',$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
```